# Will the Pi Zero version 1.3 require a new case

Tags: pi-zero, case

The new version of the Pi Zero includes a [camera connector](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/zero-grows-camera-connector/). will this require a new case or just taller standoffs and longer bolts to work with the acrylic cases like the Adafruit [Pi Protector](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2883)?

Comment: I've prepared an update to [tag:pi-models] tag information to cover this change...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sure it will be fine.  The newer zero obviously has the same footprint when viewed from above, judging by the placement of the screw holes in relation to the GPIO breakout.

The camera connector is laid on its side.  Although there's no picture besides a top shot on the Foundation blog post, in this Adafruit image:

[image]

It is appears that the connector, *at least sans the brown/black clip*, is no taller than the microUSB connectors and almost certainly shorter than the HDMI.  This would make it fairly similar to the connector to used on normal boards.

Further, that clip in the top shot from your own link obviously extends past the lip of the PCB, meaning it will be on the outside of the case.  This would be very nice if there is enough wiggle room to pull the clip in and out so you can detach the cable without loosening the bolts.

Finally, a year or so ago I accidentally ordered a model A stacked acrylic (pibow) case for a model B.  Although the basic footprint is the same, the B is much taller than the A because of the ethernet and double USB port.  The layered acrylic is fairly easy to work with using an appropriate hacksaw blade and a long metal file -- in this case if there is an issue you can probably use just the latter, and some fine grain sandpaper to finish it off (do not expect to be able to do it with just a sandpaper block, acrylic is tough stuff).

Here's a pic of that model B in the model A case taken in intense sunlight, making it easy to see my very un-pro quality hack job around the ethernet and USB ports:

[image]

However, generally it is not noticeable and the case looks good :)  The jacks jutting up give it a kind of muscle car with hood top supercharger character.

There was a lucky aspect to this accident, as pibow Model B cases at that time only allowed access to the GPIO pins via a side slot for a cable -- but the Model A cases such as that one had a top cut away.  The case is in fact level with the GPIOs, making them very easy to access on this pi (my first one from 3.25 years ago, still running fine).

Comment: +1 for the muscular car reference - someone has been playing with their hotwheels again. As for modding acrylic that is why god invented the dremel.

Comment: I was at sea at the time and had left my dremel in the van ;)

Comment: I think you mean "turbocharger" instead of "hood top blower"

Comment: @MohammadAli Actually the correct term is "supercharger": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercharger (of which "turbocharger" might be a subcategory, but they don't always involve the conspicuous hardware, I think).

Comment: @goldilocks not mesesarily , either super charger or turbo charger may be correct, turbo charger is not a subcategory of supercharger as indicated by the first chapter in the Wikipedia page you shared. But technically either supercharger or turbocharger would both fit the description of "hood top blower", the main difference being that turbo chargers are externally powered whereas super chargers are powered by the engines drive shaft.

Comment: @MohammadAli Point taken.  I'd always thought those hood top ones were only used on old carburetor engines and shaft driven.  Anyway I've edited *supercharger* in because *turbocharger* sounds like some rinky-dink thing that might be used to increase fuel economy and not just for PURE POWER!!!  Also I'm gonna change the hostname on that pi to "chevelle". ;)

Comment: @goldilocks haha, that's a great idea, glad that we have come to an agreement and I hope that you have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I just watched the latest episode of [Desk of Lady Ada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jflllBBJAxM), which discussed the new revision of the Pi Zero (Pi Zero V1.3) They specifically addressed the Pi Protector and the new Pi Zero question (including pics of the Pi with the camera cable attached). In short the Pi protector will work with the new Pi Zero V1.3.

Comment: Nice and simple, and not going on about your pi